# How to install customized Odoo modules?

Tags: module, installation, customization, odoo

I can not install customized modules on Odoo. I have made the module using scaffold command and kept the new module under addons folder. But the Process  provided here

```
 http://odoo-80.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howtos/website.html
```

does not work for me. There is no "Installed Modules" menus in my menu. The local modules menu does not list my module as well. Can anybody help?

Comment: Try checking "Technical features" in the Administrator user's settings, refreshing and choosing the "Update the module list" option.

Answer (score 0):

This [thread](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-activate-the-technical-features-7650) in odoo blog suggested how to activate "Technical Features". After that "Update Module List" will be available.